# How can I test for equality to a bound function when unit testing?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I want to test that an argument passed to a function is a function reference but the function reference is being passed using `bind()`.

Consider this code which is to be tested (shortened for brevity):

```
initialize: function () {
    this.register(this.handler.bind(this));
}
```

And this unit test to check if `register()` was called with `handler()`:

```
it('register handler', function () {
    spyOn(bar, 'register');
    bar.initialize();
    expect(bar.register.calls.argsFor(0)[0]).toEqual(bar.handler);
});
```

The arg doesn't equal the function reference I guess due to the bound function using `bind()` - how can I test that the correct function reference is being passed while still using the `bind()` method on it?

Note: This isn't specific to jasmine, I just thought it was appropriate because of the methods being used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of

```
expect(bar.register.calls.argsFor(0)[0]).toEqual(bar.handler);
```

you can do

```
expect(Object.create(bar.handler.prototype) instanceof bar.register.calls.argsFor(0)[0])
  .toBe(true);
```

or

```
expect(Object.create(bar.handler.prototype)).
  toEqual(jasmine.any(bar.register.calls.argsFor(0)[0]));
```

This works because the internal `[[HasInstance]]` method of the bound function delegates to the `[[HasInstance]]` method of the original function.

[This blog post](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/notes/note-1-ecmascript-bound-functions/) has a more detailed analysis of bound functions.

Answer (score 1):

`this.handler.bind(this)` creates completely a new function, therefore it is not equal to `bar.handler`.
See [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

You can pass bounded function as argument to your `initialize` function and then test it, e.g.:

```
var handler = bar.handler.bind(bar);
bar.initialize(handler);
expect(bar.register.calls.argsFor(0)[0]).toEqual(handler);
```

Comment: I understand that bind() is a new function - in the console, it prints out as `[native code]` so it will fail the equality test. Unfortunately, `initialize` is not expecting any arguments so I can't do that. I might be stuck and have to skip testing this as I don't want to have to change the code just to support a test. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to keep the test and code and work around it.

I spy on the function reference with an empty anon func, then call it when spying on the register method - if the spy gets called, I know it's passed the correct reference.

```
it('register handler', function () {
    spyOn(bar, 'handler').and.callFake(function(){}); // do nothing
    spyOn(bar, 'register').and.callFake(function(fn){
        fn();
        expect(bar.handler).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
    bar.initialize();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd add another approach that, to me, is a bit less awkward.

given a class like:

```js
class Bar {
  public initialize() {
    this.register(this.handler.bind(this));
  }
  private register(callback) {}
  private handler() {}
}
```

the full spec might look like:

```js
describe('Bar', () => {
  let bar;

  beforeEach(() => {
    bar = new Bar();
  });

  describe('initialize', () => {
    let handlerContext;

    beforeEach(() => {
      bar.handler = function() {
        handlerContext = this;
      };
      bar.register = jest.fn(callback => {
        callback();
      });
      bar.initialize();
    });

    it('calls register with the handler', () => {
      expect(bar.register).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.any(Function));
    });

    it('handler is context bound', () => {
      expect(handlerContext).toEqual(bar);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case (using [jest](https://jestjs.io/)) I just mocked the implementation of bind for the function I wanted and I tweaked it so that it returns the original function and not a bound copy of it.

Specifically here's what I tried and worked:

Code to be tested:

```
// module test.js

export const funcsToExecute = [];
function foo(func) {
    funcsToExecute.push(func);
}

export function bar(someArg) {
    // bar body
}

export function run(someArg) {
    foo(bar.bind(null, someArg));
}
```

I wanted to assert that when `run` is called, `funcsToExecute` contains `bar`

So I wrote the test like this:

```
import * as test from 'test';

it('should check that "funcsToExecute" contain only "bar"', () => {
    jest.spyOn(test.bar, 'bind').mockImplementation((thisVal, ...args) => test.bar);

    test.run(5);

    expect(test.funcsToExecute.length).toBe(1);
    expect(test.funcsToExecute[0]).toBe(test.bar);
});
```

For your example, I suppose it would be something like this:

```
it('register handler', function () {
    spyOn(bar, 'register');
    spyOn(bar.handler, 'bind').mockImplementation((thisVal, ...args) => bar.handler);
    bar.initialize();
    expect(bar.register.calls.argsFor(0)[0]).toBe(bar.handler);
});
```

though I haven't tested it.